# Display list of data based on id of another model chosen from collection_set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I have an app that has 2 models, City and Neighborhood. on the root page, I use collection_set to display all cities

```
<%= form_tag('/sales/neighborhood', :method => :get) %>`
  <%= collection_select(:neighborhood, :city_id, City.all, :id, :name) %>
  <%= submit_tag 'Go' %>
```

I then want to have in the following view page, a dropdown list of all neighborhoods with a city_id that matches the id of the city chosen on the first page. I think I have this part right and the city id is being passed in the params because I get a url like this `http://localhost:3000/sales/neighborhood?utf8=%E2%9C%93&city%5Bid%5D=1&commit=Go`. I just can't get a list of neighborhoods to display. I tried this in sales#neighborhood

```
<%= form_tag('sales/locations', :method => :get) %>
<%= collection_select(:location, :neighborhood_id, @nbhds.all, :id, :name) %>
<%= submit_tag 'Go' %>
```

but I get nothing in the dropdown box. I even tried this to just get a list of neighborhoods with a city_id matching the id of the city chosen like this...

```
<ul>
<% @nbhds.each do |n| %>
<li>
<%= n.name %>,
<%= n.city.name %>
</li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

I then want the application to list a set of locations based on the neighborhood_id, which would be chosen from the collection_set on the second page. Can anybody point me in the right direction? I think I've just about got it, just missing something.

My models look like this:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :state
  has_many :neighborhoods
end
```

and:

```
class Neighborhood < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :city_id, :name
  belongs_to :city
  has_many :locations
end
```

Here is the Sales controller action being called:

```
def neighborhood
@nbhds = Neighborhood.where(:city_id => params[:id])
end
```

I figure my problem is either in the where clause in sales#neighborhood or in my view but I put the code for the ul from the view in rails console and it lists all of the neighborhoods that belong to the city, the only difference is in the console I used

```
nbhds = Neighborhood.where(:city_id => 1)
```

instead of accessing it via params

I still need help with this if anyone can

Comment: What happens if you change your collection_select call to collection_select(nil, :city_id, City.all, :id, :name)?

Comment: @cheeseweasel, I tried that. Doesn't seem to make a difference. I think my problem is in accessing the GET params like in `Neighborhood.find_by_city_id(params[:id])` Does that look like the right way?

Comment: The syntax error suggests you have an issue possibly with your controller, would you post the controller action that's getting called?

Comment: @cheeseweasel I added the controller action to my post

Comment: Thanks, it looks like there should be another `end` (one for the `if` and one for the `def`), is that just a typo?

Comment: Yeah, that's a typo, sorry

Comment: @cheeseweasel, I've updated the code and explanation. If you don't mind, I'd appreciate you taking another look.

Comment: It looks like the issue is with the parameter in the url and how you're referencing it. Could you make sure the code for the initial form tag, and the url generated are current, and I'll take a look.

Comment: Thanks, @cheeseweasel, but I got it figured out. I was calling `params[:city_id]` when I should've been calling `params[:neighborhood][:city_id]`. I really appreciate your help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the collection select

```
<%= collection_select(:neighborhood, :city_id, City.all, :id, :name) %>
```

parameter you should get in your controller will be like

```
params[:neighborhood][:city_id]
```

But according to your GET url `http://localhost:3000/sales/neighborhood?utf8=%E2%9C%93&city%5Bid%5D=1&commit=Go,` it seems the two parameters you are sending is city[id]=1 and commit=Go "city%5Bid%5D=1&commit=Go"

%5B & %5D are the HTML url encoding for '[' & ']' respectively.

If this is the correct request url then in you controller you would rather use the parameter [:city][:id] than [:id]

```
def neighborhood
  @nbhds = Neighborhood.where(:city_id => params[:city][:id])
end
```

Please check your rails log to identify which is the correct params key before you start trying with any of the solution I mentioned.

Comment: thanks, I actually just figured it out before I saw your answer; but I will make yours the accepted answer as it is correct. I used params[:neighborhood][:city_id] to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

You have `city_id` as a query parameter, and yet you look for `params[:id]` in your controller.

I would change that to

```
def neighborhood
  city = City.find(params[:city_id])
  @nbhds = city.neighborhoods
end
```

If that doesn't solve your problem I'll have a better look tomorrow :)